# Live tiles not picking up image from isolated storage

Tags: file, windows-phone-7, live, tiles

Within my WP7 app, I am generating an image for a live tile and saving in Isolated storage.
It is then available for my periodic task to update the live tile with and  everything is working fine in this regard for the periodic task.

The problem I have is at the point in my foreground WP7 app when I create the live tile image I also update the live tile (since I know something has changed so why wait for the periodic task).  But when the live tile update occurs here, it seems that it cannot find the newly created file and so presents the live tile without the bitmap.

In terms of the relevant code

Creating the file

```
var source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Images/Tiles/Class Timetable with T.png", UriKind.Relative));
source.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None;
source.ImageOpened += (sender, e) => // This is important. The image can't be rendered before it's loaded.
{
    // Create our image as a control, so it can be rendered to the WriteableBitmap.
    var newImage = new Image();
    newImage.Source = source;
    newImage.Width = 173;
    newImage.Height = 173;

    // Define the filename for our tile. Take note that a tile image *must* be saved in /Shared/ShellContent
    // or otherwise it won't display.
    var tileImage = string.Format("/Shared/ShellContent/{0}.jpg", Event.UniqueId);

    // Define the path to the isolatedstorage, so we can load our generated tile from there.
    var isoStoreTileImage = string.Format("isostore:{0}", tileImage);
```

and the actual save itself

```
// Create a stream to store our file in.
var stream = store.CreateFile(tileImage);

// Invalidate the bitmap to make it actually render.
bitmap.Invalidate();

// Save it to our stream.
bitmap.SaveJpeg(stream, 173, 173, 0, 100);

// Close the stream, and by that saving the file to the ISF.
stream.Close();
```

and the code that actually  retrieves the image and updates the live tile (and works in the periodic task but not  from the app itself

```
string imageString = "isostore:/Shared/ShellContent/" + nextEvent.UniqueId + ".jpg";
ShellTile defaultTile2 = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.First();
defaultTile2.Update(new StandardTileData
{
    Title = nextTime,
    BackgroundImage = (new Uri(imageString, UriKind.Absolute)),

});
```

Just unsure as to if I am doing something fundamentally wrong here? I am considering storing the generated image in the database with its object. And, I do have a manageable number of files involved here. I am not generating hundreds of the things.

I do have a workaround which is to update the livetile from within the WP7 app without using the image file.

Comment: You're saying that it doesn't display the `BackgroundImage`, but the `Title` is updated correct?

Comment: Yes - that's right - title is there but no background image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey that code looks familiar ;-) That aside, there's nothing in the code you posted that actually can determine the problem.

My guess is that you're calling `NotifyComplete()` to early in your periodic task. For this, I recommend you use the Task Parallel Library to workaround the problem.

I actually wrote a article about it this very morning: [How To: Live Tile with Scheduled Agent](http://windcape.posterous.com/how-to-live-tile-with-scheduled-agent)

The essential part is to use [Task.ContinueWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321405.aspx) to ensure that `NotifyComplete()` is first called *after* you finished rendering the background image, and saved it to the isolated storage.

Comment: Yes - it's nice code - thanks!  Will review your article and see if that helps.

Comment: If you want a quick way to checking this, just comment out `NotifyComplete()` and see if the image is updated correctly.

Comment: I have been looking into this approach and starting to incorporate the code as per the example here.   Just a couple of questons if I may   - firstly, is the REST only required because of the example that uses  the twitter feed?  Or is it inherent in the while passing off to the UI thread.  And secondly - with this approach, can I still utilse the debug feature to have the period task actioned on a more regular basis - which is incredibly handy

Comment: 1) Yes, I use RestSharp to fetch the data from Twitter. You can replace it with any type of data feed you like. 2) Yes, shouldn't be anything preventing that.

Comment: I am struggling trying to adapt your windcape example to work in my situation.   Because in that you create an initial task as part of the process for getting the twitter feed "client.ExecuteTask<List<Tweet>>(request)"...  yet in my case I am simply filling a small collection from the database, and do not see how I can create the initial task nor how it can include my collection.  I think once I have that then I should be able to process as per your 'RunOnUIThread" method.   But that method relies   on a task to be created in its first call.

Comment: I suggest you spend some time learning how TPL works in regular C#. You **need** to understand how the async code works to work with the Windows Phone platform.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need the `isostore:` prefix on teh path when creating it within the main app. Try just creating a Relative URI to the file.

Comment: When I create it with the isostore: prefix the periodic task can find the file but the  main app cannot.  If I do as you suggest,  will the periodic task be able to see the file?

Comment: The `isostore:` prefix is very much necessary. It's actually THE reason it's at all possible to create a *local* tile. (And he ninja'd the code from one of my blog posts, so I should know)

And regardless, if the file isn't created then it's not going to work.

Comment: Because I think that may have been the issue when I tried it without the isostore: prefix.

Comment: So, if I am creating the file with the isostore: prefix, why should the main app have difficulty seeing it, since it was the app that has just created the file.

Comment: I have files saved in the main app and visible to both the app and the agent that don't use the prefix but use relative prefixes and it works fine.

Comment: Yes, files that's already there at compile-time. He's generating a new image at runtime, which then *have* to be saved in the isolated storage. And as such, the `BackgroundImage` for the tile have to be prefixed with `isostore:`

Comment: Anyway, since I wrote the original code, I can vouch for it's not related to the isostore at all.

Comment: Yes, the main app downloaded from the web and saved them to isolated storage. The image files have to be in isolated storage to be used in a tile and persist a device reboot. I'll let you work out what the issue is. :)